# Web Essentials 2013 context menu not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

Since one of the projects in my solution uses NodeJS/Grunt to compile his Less-files I have disabled the less compiling in Web Essentials using a solution-wide WebEssentials-Settings.

```
  "Less": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": false,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": false,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": false,
    "EnableChainCompilation": false,
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "StrictMath": false
  },
```

However one legacy project within this solution doesn't automatically build his Less-files, so I thought to right click the file and compile from the Web Essentials Context Menu.
Sadly whole this menu is disabled. What's the reason, how can I solve this?